# Extraction 7zip script doesn't work in Windows Server 2019 Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, 7zip, taskscheduler, windows-server-2019

I have created a ps1 script to extract a 3Gb zip folder. It works Whenever I run it from PowerShell ISE but when I add my script to windows server 2019 task scheduler it just says running and it doesn't do anything.

I tried

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
Set-location C:\
sz x -oC:/ test.zip
```

I also tried

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
Set-location C:\
7z x test.zip -oc:\ -r
```

I expect to extract the 3gbs folder.

Comment: Please copy and paste the command that was entered into Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: schtasks /create /tn "Extract" /sc onstart /delay 0000:30 /rl highest /ru system /tr "powershell.exe -file C:\scripts\setup\test.ps1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way:

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.Filesystem"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\test.zip','C:\')
```

And the way I have created the Task Scheduler:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Extract" /sc onstart /delay 0000:30 /rl highest /ru system /tr "powershell.exe -file C:\scripts\setup\test.ps1"
```

It took 4 minutes to extract a 3GB folder.
I found the solution here:
https://ridicurious.com/2019/07/29/3-ways-to-unzip-compressed-files-using-powershell/